# C#/Linq - Group by the 2nd item returned in string array whilst keep parent

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have the following data returned from an API and I am trying to use linq to re-shape the data.
Is it actually possible to do this and get the below expected result.

```
  "results": [
    {
      "Description": "Describe1",
      "Cost": 5.00,
      "Category": [
        "Online",
        "Games"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Description": "Describe2",
      "Cost": 4.00,
      "Category": [
        "Online",
        "Games"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Description": "Describe3",
      "Cost": 3.00,
      "Category": [
        "Online",
        "Grocery"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Description": "Describe4",
      "Cost": 3.00,
      "Category": [
        "Transport",
        "Bus"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Description": "Describe5",
      "Cost": 3.00,
      "Category": [
        "Transport",
        "Bus"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Description": "Describe5",
      "Cost": 10.00,
      "Category": [
        "Transport",
        "Train"
      ]
    }
}
```

The Final output I am trying to achieve from the above:

```
{ name : "Online", 
    data: [
    {
        name: Games,
        value: 9.00
    },
    {
        name : Grocery,
        value: 3.00
    }],
 name : "Transport",
 data: [
    {
        name: Bus,
        value: 6.00
    },
    {
        name : Train,
        value: 10.00
    }],
}
```

Grouping by FirstOrDefault is all easy enough for first level stats, but I can't see where to start for the sub-grouping!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is always nice to show some of your efforts before asking for help. Could you plz mention ( or update the question) with what have you tried and how far you have got?

This question is too broad. It could have multiple implementations.

Comment: Do not think the Json you expect as result is a valid one

Comment: Yes, It is possible get the output as you expect. Have you tired anything in code?

Comment: It is not possible to generate invalid json output you expecting, because it is invalid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question in two parts,

**Part 1**

The first part would consists of few steps

- Deserialize existing Json to Custom Data Structures
- Modify and create new data structures

The above steps could be achieved with Linq as following.

```
var parsedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(str).Results.GroupBy(x=> x.Category.First())
        .Select(x=>
            new {
                 name= x.Key,
                 data =  x.GroupBy(c=>c.Category.Last())
                           .Select(c=> new {value=c.Sum(f=>f.Cost),name=c.Key})
                });
```

Where RootObject is defined as

```
public class Result
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
    public List<string> Category { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

**Part 2**

The second part has to be executed depended how you want the Json to be formated. If you observe the expected result given in OP, that doesn't look like a valid Json. Simplifying it for representational purposes, the Json string looks like following

```
{ 
 name : "Online", 
 data: [....],
 name : "Transport",
 data: [...],
}
```

As observed, the name and data fields are duplicated within json. If you would like to have result in this particular manner, you need to Serialize the Json recieved in **Part 1**, and modify it using string manipulation. For example,

```
var jsonCollection =  parsedData.Select(x=> Regex.Replace(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented),@"^{|}$",string.Empty));
var finalResult = $"{{{string.Join(",",jsonCollection)}}}";
```

**Output**

```
{
  "name": "Online",
  "data": [
    {
      "value": 9.0,
      "name": "Games"
    },
    {
      "value": 3.0,
      "name": "Grocery"
    }
  ]
,
  "name": "Transport",
  "data": [
    {
      "value": 6.0,
      "name": "Bus"
    },
    {
      "value": 10.0,
      "name": "Train"
    }
  ]
}
```

If your desired result needs to be a valid json, then you could ensure it is an array. For example,

```
[
{ 
 name : "Online", 
 data: [....]
},
{
 name : "Transport",
 data: [...],
}
]
```

Then you could serialize the result you got in **Part 1** directly.

```
var finalResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedData, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Online",
    "data": [
      {
        "value": 9.0,
        "name": "Games"
      },
      {
        "value": 3.0,
        "name": "Grocery"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Transport",
    "data": [
      {
        "value": 6.0,
        "name": "Bus"
      },
      {
        "value": 10.0,
        "name": "Train"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4ve3ZN)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```cs
class ResultItem {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

class ResultGroup {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ResultItem[] Data { get; set; }
}

var results = items
    .GroupBy(x => x.Category[0])
    .Select(g => new ResultGroup {
        Name = g.Key,
        Data = g
            .GroupBy(x => x.Category[1])
            .Select(g2 => new ResultItem { Name = g2.Key, Value = g2.Sum(x => x.Cost) })
            .ToArray()
        });
```

Comment: What is `ResultGroup`? What is `ResultItem`?

Comment: Just some classes to represent your output format. I just added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in this simple way, Live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LmpiAY)

```
        var parsedJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ObjectName>>(jsonObject);
        var normalizedData = parsedJsonObject.SelectMany(pParent => pParent.Category, (pParent, pCategory) => 
                                                new { pParent, pCategory }).Select(ParentAndCategory =>
                                                                                new
                                                                                {
                                                                                    Cost = ParentAndCategory.pParent.Cost,
                                                                                    Category = ParentAndCategory.pCategory,
                                                                                }).ToList();
        var aggregatedData = new List<ObjectName2>(); 

        for(int i = 0; i < (normalizedData.Count - 1);)
        {
            aggregatedData.Add(new ObjectName2{ Cost = normalizedData[i].Cost, Category1 = normalizedData[i].Category, Category2 = normalizedData[i + 1].Category });
            i += 2;
        }

        var result = aggregatedData.GroupBy(p => p.Category1)
                                    .Select(g => new 
                                            { 
                                                name = g.Key, 
                                                data = g.GroupBy(p => p.Category2).Select(g2 => 
                                                                                          new { name = g2.Key, value = g2.Sum(p2 => p2.Cost) })
                                            }).ToList();
        foreach(var item in result)
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item));
```

**Output**

```
{"name":"Online","data":[{"name":"Games","value":9.00},{"name":"Grocery","value":3.00}]}

{"name":"Transport","data":[{"name":"Bus","value":6.00},{"name":"Train","value":10.00}]}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Harry